# terminal spins but won't open

Tags: command-line

This is my first time running ubuntu. I installed a live session of 20.04.1 LTS from a flash drive on an Intel NUC and was thrilled when the desktop GUI opened. My very first action was to find the terminal app icon and click it. The mouse turned into a spinner and then stopped. I cannot see any terminal window. Similar behavior with the firefox icon, but the file browser icon produces a window. I tried alt + ctrl + F3 which looks like a terminal interface, but that asks me for a login (how could I log in to anything? It's a fresh build unconnected to the internet!).

How can I get a terminal window open?

Comment: Changes to `.bashrc` or `.profile` can keep a terminal session 'hang'. Did you change anything?

Comment: You can log in at `tty3` (the console at Ctrl-Alt-F3) with the username and password you entered during the install. Note that anything you type after the `Password` prompt is recorded, but 'nothing' will happen with the cursor. Just type the password and hit 'enter'.

Comment: I had replaced `/usr/bin/python3` from being a symlink to `python3.8`, and instead to `python3.6` - this messed up my terminal. Reverting it to point to `python3.8` fixed it.